# How do I setup retropie to work with a 2.8inch pitft

Tags: retropie

(sorry but I'm a bit of a noob)

My question is pretty much what the title is.
I had a raspberry Pi 1 laying around so I thought I should do something fun and make a retro game arcade. I bought a 2.8inch resistive touch pitft from adafruit and connected it to my Pi like a hat. I wrote the retro pie v3.8.1 image to an 8gig sd and put it in my pie. I switch it on but it just displays white on the tft. I can view the gui threw hdmi but nothing comes threw the tft. I have tried installing different kernels and managers but in the end nothing I do seems to work. If someone could help me with a toutorial or video I would be extremely thankful.

Comment: This page might be a good starting point: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=95366

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I got it working after I posted this question. Thank you again for even bothering to answer I haven't had much luck on forums like these.

Comment: Its good to know our time is appreciated and if you keep up the superb attitude you'll go far in life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually answered my own question with the confidence that no matter what I do some verry generous person would come on here and read my post. Anyway I found this that shows you exactly what to do, and it works, with any raspberry Pi, here is the link,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4u1NKok2-BE , just don't worry about the last 15mins or so becouse it's just setting up a gamepad with the raspberry Pi 3,

Again thank you all so much, I really appreciate your support.
Angus

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.adafruit.com/running-opengl-based-games-and-emulators-on-adafruit-pitft-displays/pitft-setup

this site is what i used to set up my screen. should work for you

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I got it working after I posted this question. Thank you again for even bothering to answer I haven't had much luck on forums like these.